# How to reuse steps definition of one feature file implementation in another one in pytest_bdd?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automated-tests, pytest

I am having the below folder structure

```
folder root
    features
         file1.feature
         file2.feature
    source
         file1.py
         file2.py
```

The implementation of *file1.feature* is in *file1.py* and *file2.feature* is in *file2.py*. I was trying to reuse a step in file1.feature in file2.feature. I tried importing the method directly in file2.py as below

```
from source.file2 import method1
```

However it resulted in the below error getting triggered

```
    def _find_step_function(request, step, scenario, encoding):
        """Match the step defined by the regular expression pattern.

        :param request: PyTest request object.
        :param step: Step.
        :param scenario: Scenario.

        :return: Function of the step.
        :rtype: function
        """
        name = step.name
        try:
            # Simple case where no parser is used for the step
            return request.getfixturevalue(get_step_fixture_name(name, step.type, encoding))
        except pytest_fixtures.FixtureLookupError:
            try:
                # Could not find a fixture with the same name, let's see if there is a parser involved
                name = find_argumented_step_fixture_name(name, step.type, request._fixturemanager, request)
                if name:
                    return request.getfixturevalue(name)
                raise
            except pytest_fixtures.FixtureLookupError:
                raise exceptions.StepDefinitionNotFoundError(
                    u"""Step definition is not found: {step}."""
                    """ Line {step.line_number} in scenario "{scenario.name}" in the feature "{feature.filename}""".format(
                        step=step,
                        scenario=scenario,
>                       feature=scenario.feature,
                    )
                )    pytest_bdd.exceptions.StepDefinitionNotFoundError: Step definition is not found: Given "User is logged-in". Line 6 in scenario "Scenario 1" in the feature "../Features/file1.feature
```

Is there any way to effectively reuse the steps of one feature file in another one in pytest_bdd

Please find below feature files file1

```
Feature: Action 1

  Scenario: Creating a new Action 1
    Given User is logged-in
    And User is in Home page
    When User clicks on New in the Dashboard
    And User selects Action 1
    Then Action 1 is created
```

and file2

```
Feature: Action 2

  Scenario: Creating a new Action 2
    Given User is logged-in
    And User is in Home page
    When User clicks on New in the Dashboard
    And User selects Action 2
    Then Action 2 is created
```

Please find the stepdefinition file below for *file1.py*

```
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then

@scenario('../Features/file1.feature','Creating a new Action 1')
def test_login_page():
    pass


@given("User is logged-in")
def logging_in():
//some actions
    pass


@given("User is in Home page")
def homepage():
//some actions
        pass

@when("clicks on New in the Dashboard")
def new():
//some actions
    pass

@when("User selects Action 1")
def act1():
//some actions
        pass


@then("Action1 is created")
def logged_in():
//some actions
    pass
```

I am trying to find ways to implement stepdefinition of file2.feature in file2.py, without repeating the stepdefinitions which are already defined in file1.py. I tried importing the methods directly as below, but it resulted in the error being pasted.

```
import logging_in, homepage
```

Comment: Post the feature files.

Comment: @Guy.. its done

Comment: Thanks. It's still not very clear what exactly you are trying to do, call a function from another file? create a function with `@given` from another feature file? something else? add your code as well please.

Comment: @Guy, sorry for the confusion, I have edited the question again, please check and advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can create common steps in `conftest.py`

```
@given("User is logged-in")
def logging_in():
    print('logging_in')


@given("User is in Home page")
def homepage():
    print('homepage')
```

And add common features file `common_steps.feature`

```
Scenario: All steps are declared in the conftest
    Given User is logged-in
    Given User is in Home page
```

And add another `@scenario` to the test

```
@scenario('common_steps.feature', 'All steps are declared in the conftest')
@scenario('file1.feature', 'Creating a new Action 1')
def test_login_page():
    pass


@when("User clicks on New in the Dashboard")
def new():
    print('new')


@when("User selects Action 1")
def act1():
    print('act1')


@then("Action 1 is created")
def logged_in():
    print('logged_in')
```

**Option 2:**

Use `Background` in `common_steps.feature`

```
Feature: Common steps

Background:
    Given User is logged-in
    And User is in Home page

Scenario: Creating a new Action 1
    When User clicks on New in the Dashboard
    And User selects Action 1
    Then Action 1 is created

Scenario: Creating a new Action 2
    When User clicks on New in the Dashboard
    And User selects Action 2
    Then Action 2 is created
```

And the test

```
@scenario('common_steps.feature', 'Creating a new Action 1')
def test_login_page():
    pass


@given("User is logged-in")
def logging_in():
    print('logging_in')


@given("User is in Home page")
def homepage():
    print('homepage')


@when("User clicks on New in the Dashboard")
def new():
    print('new1')


@when("User selects Action 1")
def act1():
    print('act1')


@then("Action 1 is created")
def logged_in():
    print('logged_in')
```

**Option 3:**

Define `pytest.fixture` in `test_common.py`

```
@pytest.fixture
def common_logging_in():
    print('common logging_in')


@pytest.fixture
def common_homepage():
    print('common homepage')
```

And send it as value to the test steps

```
@scenario('file1.feature', 'Creating a new Action 1')
def test_login_page():
    pass


@given("User is logged-in")
def logging_in(common_logging_in):
    pass


@given("User is in Home page")
def homepage(common_homepage):
    pass


@when("User clicks on New in the Dashboard")
def new():
    print('new1')


@when("User selects Action 1")
def act1():
    print('act1')


@then("Action 1 is created")
def logged_in():
    print('logged_in')
```

The answer is based on ideas from [Pytest-BDD Documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pytest-bdd/downloads/pdf/latest/)

Comment: Option 1: if any of your common steps make use of a fixture defined in the conftest file, then they won't be able to find that fixture and the test will raise a FixtureLookupError. Option 2: in my opinion is not a very clean solution, since there may not be any "Common steps" features in any product. The feature files are supposed to describe the actual business features, instead of being a place fo pytest duct taping. Option 3 is only a partial solution since one still must define the steps